# 2021-02-17T05:22:18.902Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm facing this error on HyperLedger Fabric 1.4 version while trying a sample code.

I'm trying to run the Fabcar example of Hyperledger fabric. I have enrolled the admin user and registered a app user using the enrollAdmin.js and registerUser.js files respectively. However, when I try to query the ledger, I get below error:

```
Wallet path: C:\Users\badboy\fabric-samples\fabcar\javascript\wallet
2021-02-17T05:22:18.902Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
2021-02-17T05:22:18.902Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [my
channel] creator org [Org1MSP]
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
```

How do I troubleshoot this error? I ran the docker ps command and I could see the peer was in running state. I am not sure where to dig into, since I am a beginner.

Edit:

I checked into logs and found the channel was never created. Also, while running the command "peer channel list", I get below error:

```
2021-02-17 11:43:41.387 IST [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder "C:\Users\badboy\fabric-samples\config\msp" does not exist
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there were some issues with the CouchDB version. So, I had down-graded the version to 0.4.12 since my Hyperledger Fabric was on 1.4 version. Then, I reran the same commands and faced no issues.